# Error while installing e(fx)clipse plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am unable to install e(fx)clipse plugin in eclipse for my project due to some missing requirement.

I tried a bit of googling and stuff but unable to solve this issue. Though I found an alternative from here - [installing the prebuild version of eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/504671/) which solves the problem. But still I am unable to know why I couldn't install it using the repository link.

I have attached the screenshot. Any help is appreciated regarding what is the missing requirement and how to fulfil this requirement.

[image: Error I am getting]

Comment: Your screenshot indicates you’re missing a requirement.  Have you tried to install it?

Comment: Yes, i have mentioned that the error indicates that something is missing.I wanted help regarding what is missing and what to install to fulfill the requirement.